# How to get h2 Tag of a table using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, screen-scraping, jsoup

I need some help scraping a webpage with Jsoup. I want to pars player profiles from the hcfactions webpage and gather their kills and deaths. The problem I'm running into is that each profile page is dynamically created and will only have said tables if the player has kills or deaths. So in order to tell which table I'm parsing I need to get the header text that's set after the  call.

example web page: http://www.hcfactions.net/index.php?action=playerinfo&player=Djmaddox.

Below is a html segment from the web page I'm scraping:

```
<table class='table-bordered'><h2 style='text-align:center'>Deaths</h2>
    <tr><td>Date</td><td>Reason</td><td>Details</td></tr><tr><td>Dec 11 5:27pm CST</td>.....
```

I have this code that pulls the tables and counts entries but it wont pull the h2 tags with it for me to select.

```
public void getPlayerDetails(String name) {
        String data = "";
        Avatar temp = _db.getPlayer(name);
        playerUrl = "http://www.hcfactions.net/index.php?action=playersearch&player=" + name;
        try {
//            data = Jsoup.connect(url)
//                    .url(url).get().html();
            playerDoc = Jsoup.connect(playerUrl).get();
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(JParser.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        if (playerDoc.select("table").size() == 1) {
            return;
        } else if (playerDoc.select("table").size() >= 2) {

            for (int x = 1; x < playerDoc.select("table").size(); x++) {

                System.out.println("deaths");
                Element table = playerDoc.select("table").get(x);
                Iterator<Element> ite = table.select("tr").iterator();
                int count = 0;
                while (ite.hasNext()) {
                    data = ite.next().text();
                    count++;
                }

                if (count > 0) {
                    temp.setDeaths(count - 1);
                }


            }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The tag `<h2>` is on an invalid position. That's why JSoup cannot find it I think. You have to extract it yourself with regular expressions. You can get the content of the `<h2>` with the following code:

```
String tableToString = "<table class='table-bordered'><h2 style='text-align:center'>Deaths</h2>" + "<tr>" + "<td>Date</td>" + "<td>Reason</td>" + "<td>Details</td>" + "</tr>" + "</table>";
String regex = "<h2.*>(.*)?</h2>";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(tableToString);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
}
```

You can init `tableToString` with `table.toString()` from your code.

Answer (score 0):

As ka3ak says, the `<h2>` is mispositioned. But you don't have to abandon your parser as resort to regex for that. Assuming JSoup is a decent HTML parser (never used it myself) the `<h2>` element should be the element immediately preceding the `<table>` element. Get your 'select' statement to look for it there.

Answer (score 0):

`Elements headers=playerDoc.select("div.span10.offset1 h2");` 
IMHO Your selections seams to be little bit overcomplicated, but maybe it has to be like that. Anyway snippet above will get you every H2 tags present in proper container.
Later on you ca select required tables like that 
`Elements tables=playerDoc.select("div.span10.offset1 table");` 
and apply proper data digging onto them. Headers will be in corresponding order to tables ofc. I think, that my job is done here :)